# What is the use of CATKIN_DEPENDS in catkin_package (CMakeLists.txt)?

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`CATKIN_DEPENDS` parameter for the `catkin_package` function reads "*a list of catkin projects which this project depends on*".

Isn't this information already available in `package.xml`?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237431/what-is-the-use-of-catkin_depends-in-catkin_package-(cmakelists.txt)?/) by [khatribharat](https://answers.ros.org/users/26852/khatribharat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2016-06-18

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `catkin_package` macro is specifically for building C++ code; the `CATKIN_DEPENDS` (and `DEPENDS`) parameters to it  specify the packages that are needed (via their include directories, flags, and libraries) for other packages to compile against this package.

There is some overlap with the dependencies listed in `package.xml`, but `package.xml` also includes dependencies for all languages, and run-time as well as build dependencies. The dependencies listed with `CATKIN_DEPENDS` are always a subset of these dependencies, but frequently are not everything that is listed in `package.xml`.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [khatribharat](https://answers.ros.org/users/26852/khatribharat/) on 2016-06-18**:
B depends on A & C depends on B. B find_package-s, build_depend-s & run_depend-s A. C find_package-s, build_depend-s & run_depend-s B. Installing B gets B's runtime dependencies & find_package-ing B find_package-s A, so C gets A's headers & libraries as well. So B CATKIN_DEPEND-ing A isn't required.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-06-18**:
False. In the example that you give, if B provides a header that depends on a header in A, and C uses that header, C will fail to compile if B does not specify a CATKIN_DEPENDS on A. (particularly if building a three packages from source)

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-06-18**:
C does not get A's headers and libraries included in the `B_INCLUDE_DIRS` and `B_LIBRARIES` unless B explicitly lists them in `CATKIN_DEPENDS` (most times this goes unnoticed if A and B are installed from binaries and their includes are installed in the same directory)

**Comment by [khatribharat](https://answers.ros.org/users/26852/khatribharat/) on 2016-06-19**:
@^ Can you update the answer with this example? This'll be really helpful for others who visit the page.

**Comment by [khatribharat](https://answers.ros.org/users/26852/khatribharat/) on 2016-06-19**:
@ahendrix One more question, dependencies tagged using `<build_export_depend>` in package.xml, and dependencies tagged using `CATKIN_DEPENDS` and `DEPENDS` in `catkin_package` in CMakeLists.txt would always be the same set, right? So including them just in package.xml should suffice.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-06-20**:
No. `package.xml` defines **WHEN** dependencies should be installed (which circumstances, such as build or run), and `CMakeLists.txt` and the `catkin_package` function define **HOW** to use those dependencies in **C++**. (`catkin_package` does not apply to Python, for example)

**Comment by [khatribharat](https://answers.ros.org/users/26852/khatribharat/) on 2016-06-20**:
Got the *WHEN* and *HOW*. I wanted to confirm that dependencies tagged with `<build_export_depend>` in package.xml, & dependencies tagged with `CATKIN_DEPENDS`, & `DEPENDS` in CMakelists.txt are the same set. Thought catkin could automatically populate CMakelists.txt with this info from package.xml

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-06-20**:
Obviously you don't get it or you wouldn't **still** be trying to contradict my answer. catkin does not automatically populate any of that information in the CMakeLists.txt from the package.xml